# How to search as a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I'm try to find the search term in my term collection.

array of term collection  :

```
[0] "windows"
[1] "dual sim"
[2] "32 gb"
[3] "Intel i5"
```

Now I search bellow term

```
search term= "32 gb"                 return -> 2 (position of array)
search term ="android 32 gb"         return -> 2 (position of array)
search term ="android mobile 32 gb"  return -> 2 (position of array)
search term= "32 GB"                 return -> 2 (position of array)
search term= "32gb"                  return -> not match 
search term= "dual sim 32"           return -> 1 (position of array)
```

So how can do like this in C# .net
Can any search library or search dictionary provide this feature

Please advise/suggestion for same

Thanks!

Comment: You want at which position, search term found in array?

Comment: can you please share your code so far?

Comment: What should be returned when the "search term" is "windows 32 gb"? The specification here seems incredibly vague, and of course without any sort of [mcve] it's unclear what you've tried already and what _specific_ difficulty you're having solving this is.

Comment: @sami :-yes the search term found in array

Comment: @kevin; I have not any code.

Comment: @peter :  "search term" is "windows 32 gb" then returned 0

Comment: If you don't have any code at all, i.e. if you haven't even bothered to try a solution - any solution - you should not post here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Array.FindIndex` and do this.

```
var array = new string [] {"windows","dual sim","32 gb","Intel i5"};

string searchString = "android 32 gb";
var index = Array.FindIndex(array, x=> searchString.IndexOf(x) >=0);
```

if you are looking for case insensitive search, use this.

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(array, x=> searchString.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >=0);
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jpCNue)

Comment: This is the only solution so far that matches the requirements, except that you forgot to make the matching case independent. In the last line it should be: x => searchString.ToLower().IndexOf(x.ToLower()) >= 0

Comment: Also worth noting: this will return the first match.  So if your `searchString` ends up as something like `"android dual sim 32 gb"` it will return 1, the index of `dual sim` as that is the index that was hit first.

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara Can you elaborate? I agree with Jeremy that it matches first index, but I feel that's what requirement says? Am i missing something here?

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara how is this not helpful?  Did you view the demo Hari posted?  This meets all your requirements.

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara did you try the second option (case insensitive search)?

Comment: It is working :-). Checkt his [Demo](http://rextester.com/live/SVI88125)

Comment: That's a solution 
Thanks hari

Comment: @Hari You should be getting paid for this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Logic For you: Iterate through your collection(Array) in each iteration check the value with search key, if both are equals The return its Index, else return `-1`( which means item not found)

```
public static int GetMatchingIndex(string searchKey)
 {
     string[] MyValues = new string[] { "windows", "dual sim", "32 gb", "Intel i5" };
     for (int i = 0; i < MyValues.Count(); i++)
     {
          if (searchKey.IndexOf(MyValues[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
             return i;
     }
     return -1;
 }
```

You can call This Method Like the Following([Example Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yNCjek)):

```
string searchTerm = "32 gb";
int itemIndex= GetMatchingIndex(searchTerm); // This will give 2
```

Comment: my search term is "android intel i5" and return is -1 that's wrong output should  be 3

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara I had an update in the post, changed the comparison to this: ` if (searchKey.IndexOf(MyValues[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)` take a look

Answer (score -1):

```
int index =  Array.IndexOf(YourCollection,  YourCollection.Where(x=>x.Contains("32 gb")).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int SearchArray(string searchTerm) {
    return arrayList.IndexOf(
    arrayList.Cast<string>()
    .FirstOrDefault(i => searchTerm.Contains(i)));
}
```

Comment: Why use ArrayList instead of List<string> or string[] ? Also this solution has unecessary high complexetiy.

Comment: you should explain better your answer. It is not okay just post code without explanation. OP should understand what answers mean.